# How to use term id in content paths using path auto?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

How can I use term id instead of term name in path auto?I have a category field in my content type named "field_article_category" and there is a token [node:field_article_category] for it but it is replaced by term name not term id.is there anyway to get term id instead of term name?

Comment: You can select multiple terms during creating a node (if it supports multiple select). For example, if you select 2 terms for one node, you can check one of them by selecting delta. For the first selected term it should be 0, for the second term should be 1 and so on. For first term: [node:field_catalog:0:tid] - taxonomy term it for the first selected term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token you should use for the taxonomy term ID is *[node:field_article_category:id]*.

I have a "Categories" vocabulary, and this is the list of the tokens associated to that vocabulary for the nodes.

[image: screenshot]

If you install the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module, apart from having more tokens available, you will also have a list of the available tokens, from which I have taken the previous screenshot. The list is available after the fields to set the patterns for the automatic aliases, in the "Replacement patterns" fieldset.

[image: screenshot]

I have noticed that out of four vocabularies I associated with content types, only two are listed as tokens; in my case, thought, I don't see all the tokens for that vocabulary, which is different from your case, where you seem to see only part of the tokens associated with a vocabulary.

Comment: If I type "[node:field_category:tid]" I get this error: "The Pattern for all article paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_article_category:tid]".

Comment: Is your screenshot from drupal 7?

Comment: The screenshot is from Drupal 7.

Comment: If you are using "[node:field_category:tid]", why is the error for "[node:field_article_category:tid]"?

Comment: sorry, it is [node:field_article_category:tid] which causes the error.For article_category I have just one token: [node:field_article_category] which is not expandable

Comment: I am not clear why you are using "[node:field_article_category:tid]" when the field is "field_category"; if that is the field name, then you should use "[node:field_category:tid]."

Comment: Edited the main post

Answer (score 3):

You likely need the Entity tokens module from http://drupal.org/project/entity for now. We are working on adding the more detailed field tokens into Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks Dave.I installed entity and now just one of the term reference fields(I have 4 term reference fieds) is expandable.why?

Answer (score 1):

in the '**Automated alias settings**' of Pathauto you will find the section '**Taxonomy term paths**', there is a sub-section called '**Replacement patterns**'. Here you will find several patters. The pattern `[tid]` is the pattern used to show the unique ID of the taxonomy term.

I hope have understood well your question.